# How to initialize firebase, app and make them accessible in other javascript files?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vuejs2, global-variables, quasar

I am using `Quasar 2` with `firebase`. I configure `firebase` in `src/boot/firebase.js` with the following code:

```
const firebaseConfig = {...};
const app = createApp(App);
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
// State only persists in current session/tab. Cleared if session/tab is closed
firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION);
var secondaryApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig, "Secondary");

app.config.globalProperties.$fb = firebase;
app.config.globalProperties.$func = firebase.functions();
app.config.globalProperties.$func_region = firebase.app().functions("region");
app.config.globalProperties.$db = firebase.firestore();
app.config.globalProperties.$st = firebase.storage();
app.config.globalProperties.$fb_sec = secondaryApp;
app.config.globalProperties.$geo = firebase.firestore.GeoPoint;
console.log(app.config);
export default async ({ Vue, store }) => {
    const idleTimeInMillis = 900000;
  const eventsHub = Vue;
  app.use(IdleVue, {
    eventEmitter: eventsHub,
    store,
    idleTime: idleTimeInMillis,
    startAtIdle: false
  });
  app.mixin({
    methods: {
      async getInternalUserAccessControl() {
        const snapshot = await this.$db
          .doc("path/value")
          .get();
        return snapshot.data();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

and I would like to access the `app.config.globalProperties.$fb` in `src/router/index.js`:

```
export default function() {
    Router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
console.log(`index.js app.config: ${app.config}`);
        app.globalProperties.$fb.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {...});
```

The `console.log` in `index.js` shows `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to export the variable.
In src/boot/firebase.js :

```js
const firebaseConfig = {...};
export const app = createApp(App);
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

Or if you don't want to write export, you can also write :

```js
# That way you can name the variable whatever you want in the other file, make sure if you name is like : app_:app to put import { app_ } in the other file
export default { app: app };
```

In src/router/index.js :

```js
import { app } from '../boot/firebase.js';
```

I hope it will solve your problem

Comment: There is already one `export default` in the file. How can I export this default and the `app`?

Comment: You can define all component and export them all in one :
```js
export {
   app,
   function
}
```

Comment: How to export default and `app`?

Comment: There can only be one export default in a file, I'd recommend to leave it as it and just export const app = ...;